# How to convert an Array to a Set in Java

Tags: java, collections, arrays, set

I would like to convert an array to a Set in Java. There are some obvious ways of doing this (i.e. with a loop) but I would like something a bit neater, something like:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(Object[] a);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1406, accepted):

Like this:

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

In Java 9+, if unmodifiable set is ok:

```
Set<T> mySet = Set.of(someArray);
```

In Java 10+, the generic type parameter can be inferred from the arrays component type:

```
var mySet = Set.of(someArray);
```

**Be careful**

> Set.of throws IllegalArgumentException - if there are any duplicate
> elements in someArray.
> See more details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)

If you want an unmodifiable set and you might have duplicate elements in the array, do the following:

```
var mySet = Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: I would leave out the last <T>, otherwise nice oneliner!

Comment: @SLaks Exactly. asList just creates a view on top of the array.

Comment: @SLaks I exaggerated a bit. But you still create 1 more object than if you iterated over the array yourself or used the helper method provided by Collections, as indicated by JavadocMD below. That is unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Note that if you use this method on an array of primitives such as int[] it will return a List<int[]> so you should use wrapper classes to get the intended behavior.

Comment: Actually, if you put the code in a method with a generic return type <T>, attempting to pass a primitive array as T[] won't compile, so no problem. Otherwise, one would need to check someArray.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive().

Comment: Sets.newHashSet is a cleaner solution

Comment: @AjayGautam: That's only in Guava.

Comment: I'll take readability over efficiency (nearly) every time: http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/

Comment: @yegor256 The valid explicit syntax is `Arrays.<T>asList()`. But it is better to rely on type inference whenever possible.

Comment: Set<String> set = Collections.asSet("one", "two");

Comment: There is a major difference between using  new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray)); and Set.of(someArray); that is, former produces a Non-Immutable collection while later produce an immutable collection.

Comment: I observed that  new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray)); would not add each element separately , it just adds the whole array as set's first item .

Comment: The time complexities of all of these solutions are O(n), correct? I assume there is no faster way to do it.

Comment: @SLaks - how would I convert an array of primitive integers to a TreeSet of Integers ?

Comment: Arrays.asList(someArray)); will not work for `int[] someArray`

Comment: `Set.of(someArray);` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` in case `someArray` has duplicate item(s) while `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(someArray));` would create the set successfully.

Answer (score 246):

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>();
Collections.addAll(mySet, myArray);
```

That's [Collections.addAll(java.util.Collection, T...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) from JDK 6.

Additionally: *what if our array is full of primitives?*

For JDK < 8, I would just write the obvious `for` loop to do the wrap and add-to-set in one pass.

For JDK >= 8, an attractive option is something like:

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: You can do that with `java.util.Collections.addAll`. Plus, I wouldn't recommend Commons Collections anymore, what with it not being generified and Guava existing .

Comment: +1 for being more efficient than SLaks's answer, even though it's not a one-liner.

Comment: @Adrian I question that. I think `addAll` will be O(_n_).

Comment: I believe Adrian's point was about how SLaks' solution creates a List instance which is ultimately thrown out. The actual impact of that difference is *probably* extremely minimal, but *could* depend on the context in which you're doing this -- tight loops or very large sets might behave very differently between these two options.

Comment: Per the Collections.addAll() javadoc (Java 6): "The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations."

Comment: Interesting fact? Coding in NetBeans, I wrote my own loop to copy the array to the set. NetBeans popped up a light bulb suggesting I use `mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));`

Comment: @user2418306 Indeed! Of course you can't have a collection of primitives anyway, so you're going to have to wrap them. Edited with recommendations.

Comment: JDK 9+ (not primitives): `Set.of(myArray)`

Comment: This should be the real answer simply for the built in method `Collections.addAll(java.util.Collection, T...)`

Answer (score 127):

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can do:

```
T[] array = ...
Set<T> set = Sets.newHashSet(array);
```

Comment: also ImmutableSet.copyOf(array).  (I like to point out also's, I guess.)

Comment: For a fixed list of elements you could use: ImmutableSet.of(e1, e2, ..., en). Notice you would not be able to change this Set after its creation.

Comment: Be warned, the Guava javadoc says: "This method is not actually very useful and will likely be deprecated in the future." They point towards the standard `new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray))`. See https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(E...)

Answer (score 71):

Java 8:

```
String[] strArray = {"eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier"};

Set<String> strSet = Arrays.stream(strArray).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(strSet);
// [eins, vier, zwei, drei]
```

Comment: Is it worth doing this in parallel?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian This is not necessarily being done in parallel. Arrays.stream does not make any promises on the stream. You would have to call parallel() on the resulting stream for that.

Comment: You could also call parallelStream(). To answer @RaffiKhatchadourian's question, probably not. Try measuring if you're noticing any performance issues.

Comment: Generally, avoid parallel. By default it uses a single threadpool accross your application, and the overhead to start threads and join is worse than sequentially streaming through hundreds of items. Only in very few situations does parallel actually bring benefit.

Answer (score 51):

Varargs will work too!

```
Stream.of(T... values).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: way better that 2-3 liners.

Answer (score 37):

### Java 8

We have the option of using `Stream` as well. We can get stream in various ways:

```
Set<String> set = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D").collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
System.out.println(set);

String[] stringArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
Set<String> strSet1 = Arrays.stream(stringArray).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(strSet1);

// if you need HashSet then use below option.
Set<String> strSet2 = Arrays.stream(stringArray).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
System.out.println(strSet2);
```

The source code of `Collectors.toSet()` shows that elements are added one by one to a `HashSet` but specification does not guarantee it will be a `HashSet`.

> "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the Set returned."

So it is better to use the later option. The output is:

`[A, B, C, D]
[A, B, C, D]
[A, B, C, D]`

### Immutable Set (Java 9)

Java 9 introduced `Set.of` static factory method which returns immutable set for the provided elements or the array.

```
@SafeVarargs
static <E> Set<E> of​(E... elements)
```

Check [Immutable Set Static Factory Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#immutable) for details.

### Immutable Set (Java 10)

We can also get an immutable set in two ways:

1. `Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(array))`
2. `Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());`

The method `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` internally makes use of `Set.of` introduced in Java 9. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536126/1216775) of mine for more.

Comment: +1 for `Stream.of()` - I didn't know that one. A small quibble about `Collectors.toSet()`: you say the spec does not guarantee adding elements one by one, but that's what it means by: "accumulates ... into a new `Set`". And it's more readable - so preferable to my mind, if you don't need the guarantees of concrete type, mutability, serializability and thread-safety.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Spec does not guarantee that the set implementation will be `HashSet`. It only guarantees that it will be a `Set` and that is what I mean. Hope I clarified it.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks, I misread it as meaning "spec does not guarantee added one by one" rather than "spec does not guarantee a HashSet". Proposed an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 19):

After you do `Arrays.asList(array)` you can execute `Set set = new HashSet(list);`

Here is a sample method, you can write:

```
public <T> Set<T> GetSetFromArray(T[] array) {
    return new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a method that returns a set directly from an array, does one exist?

Comment: You can write your own, if you are so eager:)

Answer (score 18):

There has been a lot of great answers already, but most of them won't work with array of primitives (like `int[]`, `long[]`, `char[]`, `byte[]`, etc.)

In Java 8 and above, you can box the array with:

```
Integer[] boxedArr = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Then convert to set using stream:

```
Stream.of(boxedArr).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 12):

In [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), the following will work:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = Sets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Set<Integer> set2 = Sets.mutable.of(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
MutableSet<Integer> mutableSet = Sets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
ImmutableSet<Integer> immutableSet = Sets.immutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

Set<Integer> unmodifiableSet = Sets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asUnmodifiable();
Set<Integer> synchronizedSet = Sets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asSynchronized();
ImmutableSet<Integer> immutableSet = Sets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toImmutable();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 7):

Quickly : you can do :

```
// Fixed-size list
List list = Arrays.asList(array);

// Growable list
list = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(array));

// Duplicate elements are discarded
Set set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array));
```

and to reverse

```
// Create an array containing the elements in a list
Object[] objectArray = list.toArray();
MyClass[] array = (MyClass[])list.toArray(new MyClass[list.size()]);

// Create an array containing the elements in a set
objectArray = set.toArray();
array = (MyClass[])set.toArray(new MyClass[set.size()]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I've written the below from the advice above - steal it... it's nice!

```
/**
 * Handy conversion to set
 */
public class SetUtil {
    /**
     * Convert some items to a set
     * @param items items
     * @param <T> works on any type
     * @return a hash set of the input items
     */
    public static <T> Set<T> asSet(T ... items) {
        return Stream.of(items).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays.stream may be better than Stream.of for the above.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime using some standard libraries helps a lot. Try to look at the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). In this case your problems is simply transformed to something like this

```
String[] keys = {"blah", "blahblah"}
Set<String> myEmptySet = new HashSet<String>();
CollectionUtils.addAll(pythonKeywordSet, keys);
```

And here is the [CollectionsUtils javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html)

Comment: user might not use apache commons

Comment: if the user does not use apache commons, then that is his first mistake.

Comment: why would you use this instead of `java.util.Collections.addAll(myEmptySet, keys);`??

Answer (score 0):

```java
private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> nobreaks = new HashMap();
nobreaks.put(1, new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new int[]{2, 4, 5})));
System.out.println("expected size is 3: " +nobreaks.get(1).size());
```

the output is

```
expected size is 3: 1
```

change it to

```java
nobreaks.put(1, new HashSet(Arrays.asList( 2, 4, 5 )));
```

the output is

```
expected size is 3: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Java 10**:

```
String[] strs = {"A", "B"};
Set<String> set = Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(strs));
```

[`Set.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) returns an unmodifiable `Set` containing the elements of the given `Collection`.

The given `Collection` must not be `null`, and it must not contain any `null` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CollectionUtils` or `ArrayUtils` from `stanford-postagger-3.0.jar`

```
import static edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArrayUtils.asSet;
or 
import static edu.stanford.nlp.util.CollectionUtils.asSet;

  ...
String [] array = {"1", "q"};
Set<String> trackIds = asSet(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone solving for Android:

### Kotlin Collections Solution

The asterisk `*` is the `spread` operator. It applies all elements in a collection individually, each passed in order to a `vararg` method parameter. It is equivalent to:

```
val myArray = arrayOf("data", "foo")
val mySet = setOf(*myArray)

// Equivalent to
val mySet = setOf("data", "foo")

// Multiple spreads ["data", "foo", "bar", "data", "foo"]
val mySet = setOf(*myArray, "bar", *myArray)
```

Passing no parameters `setOf()` results in an empty set.

In addition to `setOf`, you can also use any of these for a specific hash type:

```
hashSetOf()
linkedSetOf()
mutableSetOf()
sortableSetOf()
```

This is how to define the collection item type explicitly.

```
setOf<String>()
hashSetOf<MyClass>()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build an immutable set with only one element inside it, you can use `Collections.singleton(...)`. Here is an example:

```java
Set<String> mySet = Collections.singleton("Have a good day :-)");
```

<sub><sub>This doesn't answer the original question but might be useful to someone (it would have been at least to me). If you think this answer does not fit just tell me and I will delete it.</sub></sub>

Answer (score -1):

`new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.asList(Object[] a));`

But I think this would be more efficient:

```
final Set s = new HashSet<Object>();    
for (Object o : a) { s.add(o); }
```

Comment: That wouldn't really be more efficient (at least not worth thinking about).

Comment: With the constructor version, the initial capacity of the `HashSet` is set based on the size of the array, for instance.

Comment: this answer is not so dumb as it seems: 'Collections.addAll(mySet, myArray);' from  java.util.Collections use the same iterator but plus one boolean operation . Plus as  Bert F pointed out Collections.addAll " likely to run significantly faster under most implementations" than c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements))

Answer (score -4):

```
Set<T> b = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(requiredArray));
```

Comment: In what aspect does you answer differ from the implementation @SLaks has provided as least 6 years ago? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3064447