# Need to pass a String array to a Set

Tags: java

Hello guys I need to pass a string array over to a setter that takes a Set. Not sure how to pass it over. Thanks

THis is my form:

```
  public String[] getFields() { return fields; }
public void setFields(String[] s) 
{ 
    fields = s; 
    //System.out.println("form Array length " + s.length);  
}
```

and here is the bean:

```
private Set<FieldBean> fields;

   public void setFields( Collection<FieldBean> val )
{
    t
    if( fields == null ) fields = new HashSet<FieldBean>();
    fields.addAll( val );
}
```

Action code:

```
ParameterBean paramBean = new ParameterBean();  
form.getFields()  y

        paramBean.setFields(Arrays.asList(form.getFields()));  //Need bean set here
```

got a message that stated: The method setFields(Collection) in the type ParameterBean is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Comment: Are there duplicates in the array, because that is the requirement for a Set?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set) thread.

Comment: @WebUser: `addAll` will ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass [`Arrays.asList(fields)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
new HashSet<..>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

will give you a set. But since you already have the `addAll(..)` method, you just need a collection, which is `Arrays.asList(array)`

Btw, normally a setter just takes a value and sets it. Having this kind of logic within the setter is not always a good idea. So check if you could make it a simple setter and use the first line of my answer.

Comment: I added 'paramBean.setFields(Arrays.asList(form.getFields()));' and got the message:  "The method setFields(Collection<DetFieldBean>) in the type DetParameterBean is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)"

Comment: Your setter needs a Set of type DetParameterBean, you can't convert a String into DetParameterBean. What's the content of DetParameterBean?

Comment: It's still the same problem. Your form returns an Array of type String. The bean setter wants a Collection of type DetParameterBean. I am not sure what your task is, but this wont work. Your form might return an Array of type DetParameterBean, or there is a way to create DetParameterBean out of an String (but I doubt that).

Comment: that took away the error...hope it works :)...Now time to send to database

Answer (score 0):

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
myMethod(ImmutableSet.copyOf(stringArray));
```

(Simpler, faster, and less memory-intensive than `HashSet`.)