# splitting a large string into SET items

Tags: java, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - easily convert array to set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set)

Can someone help me with a version of the following expression that I can use for SET instead of ArrayList ?

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(comment.split(", ")));
```

P.S.: Comment is a large string of words split  with a `","`. Need to make an individual item of the word by splitting them from the comma sections.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You use the same approach, just passing the converted array to the constructor of a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation:

```
Set<String> items = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(comment.split(", ")));
```

Further simplification are not possible without third-party libraries, but there are no drawbacks, since `Arrays.asList` executes in constant time *O(1)*.