# Does .asSet(...) exist in any API?

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for a very simple way to create a Set.

`Arrays.asList("a", "b" ...)` creates a `List<String>`

Is there anything similar for `Set` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - easily convert array to set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set)

Comment: it's not, creating a Set and converting an Array to a Set is not the same thing

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Now with Java 8 you can do this without need of third-party framework:

```
Set<String> set = Stream.of("a","b","c").collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

See [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

Enjoy!

Comment: Now, whoever said that Java was too verbose? Of course this is the best answer!

Comment: Thank's a lot @BobDoolittle !

Comment: For anyone using java 9+ please also see Holly's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48025159/229743

Comment: I still prefer use the Java 8 "Stream way" than the Java 9 feature, because "collectors" allow you to customize the resulting collection (may be "List", "Set" or any custom structure desired), while the utils of java 9 must be called separatedly for each collection type (and not all structures have an corresponding "util" ).

Comment: flawless answer Mr. Anderson!

Answer (score 68):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it is as simple as that:

```
Set<String> mySet = ImmutableSet.<String> of("a", "b");
```

Or for a mutable set:

```
Set<String> mySet = Sets.newHashSet("a", "b")
```

For more data types see the [Guava user guide](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained)

Comment: Is there a non-immutable version of this?

Comment: @cahen yes: `Sets.newHashSet("a", "b")` or `Sets.newLinkedHashSet("a", "b")`

Comment: I added a mutable variant to the answer.

Comment: actually, `Sets.newLinkedHashSet()` does not exist with that signature, sorry

Comment: I was able to remove one of the type arguments: `Set<String> mySet = ImmutableSet.of("a", "b");`

Comment: @joshden That will work only in java 7+, which included the diamond operator

Answer (score 63):

You could use

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b"));
```

Comment: I would rather do this then use the stream version. I can simply statically import "asList", making this even less verbose.

Answer (score 30):

In Java 9, similar function has been added via factory methods:

```
Set<String> oneLinerSet = Set.of("a", "b", ...);
```

(There are equivalents for `List` as well.)

Comment: I tried this and got a compiler warning that this is not an API method.

Comment: Here's the relevant java doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html. As well as using a Java 9+ JDK, you may need to adjust your IDE or build tool to use Java 9 compliance (for example, for maven, it would be similar steps to those here, but set to 1.9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798066/set-default-java-compliance-level-for-maven-projects-in-eclipse)

Comment: Wish we could use Java 9.. We're living in the past! :(

Comment: that is good but have some restrictions on the size of the arguments...

Answer (score 28):

For the special cases of sets with zero or one members, you can use:

```
java.util.Collections.EMPTY_SET
```

and:

```
java.util.Collections.singleton("A")
```

Comment: for these special cases,  it is likely the best solution as it uses the standard java.util API

Comment: `java.util.Collections.emptySet()` is, in my mind, preferred over EMPTY_SET, due to type safety. From the comments in the Collections class: `Unlike the like-named field, this method is parameterized.`

Answer (score 22):

As others have said, use:

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b"));
```

The reason this does *not* exist in Java is that `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed sized list, in other words:

```
public static void main(String a[])
{
  List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
  myList.add("c");
}
```

Returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
```

There is no JDK implementation of a "fixed-size" `Set` inside the `Arrays` class. Why do you want this? A `Set` guarantees that there are no duplicates, but if you are typing them out by hand, you shouldn't need that functionality... and `List` has more methods. Both interfaces extend `Collection` and `Iterable`.

---

As others have said, use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) If you really want this functionality - since it's not in the JDK. Look at their answers (in particular Michael Schmeißer's answer) for information on that.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, because it points out what Arrays.asList() actually does. Many devs seem to believe that Arrays.asList() creates a java.util.ArrayList, while it actually creates a java.util.Arrays$ArrayList (which is only partially mutable and a live view of the underlying array)

Comment: As to why someone would want to do this, the most common reason to construct a Set (or List) by hand is in a test class where you are passing in test values.

Answer (score 6):

No but you can do it like this

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", ...));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little method you can use

```
  /**
   * Utility method analogous to {@link java.util.Arrays#asList(Object[])}
   *
   * @param ts
   * @param <T>
   * @return the set of all the parameters given.
   */
  @SafeVarargs
  @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
  public static <T> Set<T> asSet(T... ts) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ts));
  }
```

Comment: I actually wrote this exact same solution--nice!

Answer (score 3):

In [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you could use

```
Set<String> set = Sets.newHashSet("a","b","c");
```

[newHashSet](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet%28E...%29)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it using Java 8 and enums would be:

```
Set<String> set = EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.READ);
```

See [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

I would recommend a performance analysis between this approach and

```
Set<String> set = Stream.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.READ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

because if you have more than five elements the javadoc of the method states that may be performance issues as you can see in the javadoc of [Set.Of(E, E...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#of-E-E...-).

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
myList.add("c");
System.out.println(myList);
```

It worked without error

Comment: This answer as is atm doesn't create a `Set`