# Set default java compliance level for Maven projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

The default compliance level for Maven is 1.5 and every time that I update a maven project in Eclipse it sets back the compliance level from 1.6 to 1.5 which is really annoying for me.

I know that I can set the target to 1.6 in the POM file but the problem is that I cannot set this in the parent POM and expect the children to inherit it. So I have to do it for every single Maven module. How can I set it in my Maven project or in the whole eclipse once for a "lifetime" without modifying every single Maven module!?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I know that I can set the target to 1.6 in pom file but the problem is that I cannot set this in the parent pom and expect the children to inherit it.

Setting the `<source>` and `<target>` version in the parent pom does work.

For example, in my parent pom, I have:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

If you are having problems, you might want to check that:

- the child specifies the correct version of the parent;
- the parent pom specifies both `source` and `target` values;
- you have run `mvn install` on the parent; and
- `mvn help:effective-pom` on the child project shows the expected source/target values.

After modifying the poms, you may need to select both projects and use *Maven->Update Project*.

Comment: This is somehow odd for me because I'd already tried putting the above tags in my parent pom a while ago and it didn't work at that time!! But now it is working. Seems like that I forgot some xml tags at that time because it is working now. Btw. thank you for the help and saving me the hassle of setting back java compliance level every time after maven update!

Comment: What file do I need to put the XML snippet in?  (I don't know what a parent POM is).

Answer (score 4):

Another way (if you do not have already compiler plugin defined) is to set just these properties in your **pom** file:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**Details**: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me..

```
<build>
<finalName>ProjectName</finalName>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the project's pom.xml and insert below in between  tags. Then the eclipse plugin (like m2eclipse) should rebuild the workspace.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: this is project-level as only the project's pom.xml is affected.

Comment: I have fixed same problem to put this code into pom.xml