# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) for lambda expression

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, syntax-error

I have encountered a syntax problem in the following code used for Threading:

```
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            new Thread(() -> {
                GrabberShowUsesCallable gs = new GrabberShowUsesCallable();
                //GrabberShow gs = new GrabberShow();
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Future<String> future = executorService.submit(gs);
                String cc;
                try {
                    //Add data to table
                    cc = future.get();
                    model.addRow(new Object[] {row,0,cc,0});
                    row=row+1;
                    Thread.currentThread().stop();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

I got error at line 3 new thread:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
>        construct(s)
>       - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
>        tokens

In that line I got two syntax error, one from **(**()

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

and one from **->** {

> Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

The code was running fine on 3 different laptops, except one (my laptop) encountered this problem. I am using Eclipse with jre 8.0 and jdk 8.0 installed.

Comment: Are your Eclipse project settings also on Java 8?

Comment: Apart from errors / warnings, code has some serious issue, nested threads creation.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed out one line, I just updated the code again

Comment: @MuratK. I'm not sure about that?

Comment: Why are you submitting a job to an executor service when you are immediately calling `get()` on the future? When you’re not doing anything asynchronously, call `gs.call()` directly. And why on Earth are you calling `stop()` on the thread? Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--)? And the line `model.addRow(new Object[] {row,0,cc,0});` suggests that you are modifying a Swing model from a background thread, so you should read [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) first.

Comment: Project settings: In _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ is the _Compiler compliance level_ set to _1.8_?

Comment: Just for the record: a lambda within an anonymous class? Maybe stick to **one** concept? And seriously: this code is doing quite some work. How do you unit test a lambda in an anonymous class? Probably not at all. So, seriously: consider not doing that. Put your code into units that allow you to *test* them.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your java source level is java8 too, in the eclipse project settings overrides, if the eclipse default is not java8 source level. This is a typical overlook.

Answer (score 1):

If https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173565/139985 (setting the compiler source level) doesn't solve your problem, then here are a couple more things to check.

Lambda expressions are a Java 8+ feature, so:

- Check that your JDK / JRE is Java 8 or later.
- Check that you are using a version of Eclipse that supports Java 8.  The first major release of Eclipse to support Java 8 "out of the box" was [Eclipse Luna (R 4.4)](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/june/article1.php).

Also, if you are using Maven, make sure that the Maven POM file explicitly specifies the Java source level:

- [Set default java compliance level for maven projects in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798066/set-default-java-compliance-level-for-maven-projects-in-eclipse)

The default source for Maven is Java 5, and this will clobber the source level you set in the Eclipse settings for your project.