# Collection of objects in Flex to Java Set

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, set, arraycollection

My frontend is Flex and backend is in Java. My flex and java layers communicate using the remote objects logic. Suppose I have a class A and B in Flex and Java layers. Class A will have an arraycollection of B type objects as a member. I want to convert it to a Set on Java side. How do I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set

Comment: Well actually I figured out the issue with my code. The Arraycollection can be directly converted into Set on java side implicitly. The mistake I made was making the Arraycollection private rather than public. Thank you.