# How to randomly distribute all elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, double

I have an array that contains the `int` values 1, 2, and 3 and I want to randomly assign all of those values to three different variables (without repeating any of the values). This is what I've gotten so far, but when I tested it, it would sometimes duplicate one of the values.

**Question: How can I randomly distribute all of the elements of an array to several different variables?**

```
//method     
    public static double calculate(int randomVal[]){
            Random random = new Random();
            double randomAnswer = 0;
            for(int i = 0;i < randomVal.length; i++){
              randomAnswer = (randomVal[random.nextInt(randomVal.length)]);
            }
            return randomAnswer;   



//create array
 int[] randomVal = new int[] {1,2,3};

double solution1 = MathGame.calculate(randomVal);
double solution2 = MathGame.calculate(randomVal);
double solution3 = MathGame.calculate(randomVal);
```

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array). After shuffling then you can assign to variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use an `Integer[]` then you might use [`Collections.shuffle(List<?>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and then [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to display it like

```
Integer[] randomVal = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(randomVal));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomVal));
```

Comment: So after I do Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(randomVal)); I could then assign those three variables and it would work?

Comment: @Jordan `randomVal` is an array. You could read the three distinct values like `int a = randomVal[0]; int b = randomVal[1]; int c = randomVal[2];` (the interface you've defined doesn't appear to access the array with an index), also it's an array of `int`(s) not `double`(s).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can shuffle an array of ints

```
void shuffle(int[] a) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = a.length; i > 1; i--) {
        int r = rnd.nextInt(i);
        int t = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[r];
        a[r] = t;
    }
}
```

then just use its elements

```
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    shuffle(a);
    double solution1 = a[0];
    double solution2 = a[1];
    double solution3 = a[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just let Java handle it and using a set as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set)

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray));

Iterator<T> it=mySet.iterator();

//assign variables using it.next();
```