# Why doesn't implicit casting happen here?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm looking to convert an array of `char` to a `Set` of Characters.

Logically if I wrote out something like [How to convert an Array to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/java-easily-convert-array-to-set) instead of using the built in functions it would work.  However using built in functions with generics it does not.

```
    TreeSet<Character> characterSet = Sets.newTreeSet();

    String myString = "string";
    Character [] characterArray = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};


    Collections.addAll(characterSet,characterArray); // This works
    Collections.addAll(characterSet,myString.toCharArray()); // This Does not
```

Why doesn't it cast array of `char` to `characters`?

As a follow up to an answer.  (Thank you btw)  I think a simple example of what I mean is why does the first line implicitly cast but the second line does not?

```
    Character [] characterArray  = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'}; // works
    Character [] characterArray2 = myString.toCharArray(); // does not work
```

My understanding is both of the right hand sides make `character[]` variabless

Comment: To make it short: there is no autoboxing from "primitive type array" to "wrapper type array".

Comment: You mean `myString.toCharArray()` is not the same type as `{'s','t','r','i','n','g'}`?

Comment: Read what @kocko wrote about that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `myString.toCharArray()` will return `char[]` which is not `Character[]`. You can verify it by this simple test:

```
char[] a = { 'a' };
Character[] b = { 'b' };
a = b; //doesn't work, because char[] is not a Character[]
```

The `Character[] characterArray = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};` however is compliant with `Collections.addAll(...)`, because when the array is initialized, each of the values is autoboxed from `char` to `Character`.

Comment: Why does using `{'s','t','r','i','n','g'}` work in my second example then?  Doesn't that return type `char[]`?

Comment: Each of the values, as I've stated, are autoboxed to `Character`, which finally results in `Character[]`. This is a feature of the array initializer

Comment: Ah.  I didn't realize it had special rules https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6 Thanks!