# Save String Array in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I have a String Array from a server and I want to save the string array in `sharedPreferences`to avoid further server calls to retrieve the string array.

This is my String array below:

```
String[] names = new String[response.body().getData().size()];

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putStringSet("walletTypes", names);
```

Unfortunately I can't put the String Array in a `StringSet`, anybody have an idea how I can save my String array in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Did you called apply() or commit() on the editor after putting the array?

Comment: Convert your string array to json string using GSON and put it in preference

Comment: the error says wrong second argument type. Found java.lang.String[] Required java.util.Set<java.lang.String>

Comment: @Cata yes i call commit()

Comment: BTW, your `names` array still empty?! you only created array with size equal to response size, but no content ?! is that what you want?

Comment: other than that, have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-set-in-java

Comment: The error says it all, you need a set of String objects and not an array there. You need to change the array to a Set.
To do that (if you don't know), take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-set-in-java

Comment: Thank you..your solution helped me.