# Set of cities in Java

Tags: java, set

In my task I already put some cities in array but I now face a problem.

In main i did this:

```
City[] cities = enterCity(scanner);
```

In method enter city I had array of 3. So I needed to return name of a city and number of citizens.
In for loop I enter name and number of citizens. At the end of loop I did this:

```
cities[i]=new City(name, numbersOfCitizens);
```

and then returned it with City[] cities.
Now I need to improve my code with set.

In method I implemented:

```
Set<City> cities = new Hashset<>();
```

I failed to create method add. I tried with this to call it in main:

```
add.(City(name, numbersOfCitizens));
```

in City class and return City[] cities says inconvertible types ( so it cannot return anything). Is the right thing to call method like I do in main and if it is how to properly return all values. In class City I have usual get and set method.

Comment: Which type you have to return from method - array or set?

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064447/5178499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create `Set`

```
// Create new Set 
Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>();

// Add new City
cities.add(new City());
```

## Convert `Set` in to array - option #1

```
City[] objects = cities.toArray(new City[0]);
```

## Convert `Set` in to array - option #2

Manual copy:

```
City[] objects = new City[cities.size()];
int position = 0;

for (City city : cities) {
    objects[position] = city;
    position++;
}
```

## Working example

```
public class SetExample {

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Set<City> cities = readCities();
    }

    private static Set<City> readCities() {
        Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>();
        int numberOfCities = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCities; i++) {
            City newCity = readCity();
            cities.add(newCity);
        }

        return cities;
    }

    private static City readCity() {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Numbers of citizens: ");
        int numbersOfCitizens = scanner.nextInt();

        return new City(name, numbersOfCitizens);
    }
}
```

## Printing

Example of the class:

```
class City {
    private String name;
    private int numbersOfCitizens;

    public City(String name, int numbersOfCitizens) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numbersOfCitizens = numbersOfCitizens;
    }
}
```

When you will use without adding `toString()` method so:

```
City city = new City("New York", 1234);
System.out.println(city);
```

you can expect output:

```
City@19469ea2
```

To print custom message, you have to override `toString()` method, for example generate "default" method in IntelliJ:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "City{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", numbersOfCitizens=" + numbersOfCitizens +
            '}';
}
```

or something simple like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + numbersOfCitizens;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.

Comment: @Qyz added more information about that :)

Comment: Solved, now im facing problem how to access something like city[i].name but sets dont have indexes. I'll spend some time with this task :)

Comment: So instead of `Set<City>` use `List<City>` (e.g. with `ArrayList`)

Comment: For cities I must use Sets.