# How do I create a mutable set from an already created array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, set

I have made this array of cards using enumerators for the suit and rank, but it is immutable. I cannot remove anything from the `Deck`. I can use `shuffle` by using

```java
void shuffle() {
    List<Card> shuffold = Arrays.asList(cards);
}
```

I cannot use `remove` to deal cards even when using `Arrays.asList(cards)` I don't want to use a new deck every time I deal a card only when starting a new hand. Should I make the `Deck` an `ArrayList` or can I somehow convert it to a mutable set or is that even possible?

```java
public class Deck {
    public final Card[] cards;
    public Deck() {
        cards = new Card[52];
        int i = 0;
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
                cards[i++] = new Card(rank, suit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can already use `shuffle` but the array is still immutable in that I cannot use this to remove the first card in the deck:

```java
void deal() {
    Collection deal = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(cards));
    deal.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an Array to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064423/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-set-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a deck to be a `List` so it has an order, but that's easy enough.  Just write

```
List<Card> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cards));
```

or if you really want a set

```
Set<Card> shuffled = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(cards));
```

Answer (score 1):

The main feature of the [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method is that the returned list is backed by the specified array, so you can use the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) methods on the array through this list. And since the array is of a *fixed-size*, this list is also of a *fixed-size*, but you can *shuffle* it or change it in some other way.

To specify the type of the returned collection, you can use the *Java 8* [`toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) method:

```java
String[] arr = {"A", "B", "C"};

HashSet<String> set = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

set.add("D");

System.out.println(set); // [A, B, C, D]
```